# For 40 watts Battery what should be the Battery power required?

Tags: led, batteries

For 40 watts LED Bulb what should be the Operating Battery power required??

Comment: At least 40W. If you want to know what battery voltage and capacity that you need, then you will have to tell us what sort of LED you have (a datasheet would be useful), and how long you want the LED to be lit.

Comment: Battery must have be a matched V or current source ( CC) and have adequate Ah and charger to sustain W load. You better improve your question with better specs. Time, voltage, LED datasheet

Comment: From an engineering point of view your question makes little sense. A battery contains **energy**, this can be released slowly (1 W for 40 hours) or quickly (40 W for 1 hour). In both cases the battery delivers 40 WattHour of energy. Some batteries can only deliver the power slowly, this depends on their type. You will need some electronics to limit the current through the LED.

Answer (score 2):

The battery will need to be able to supply 40W.

But, that doesn't help.

You probably want to run the lights for more than a split second, so you will need to specify how long.

You will also need to know the voltage of the battery and the required voltage and current for the light.

Lets say your battery supplies 12V, and the LED light can run on 12V.  That means that it draws about 40W/12V= 3.3Amperes.  Batteries are usually rated in Ampere hours.  So, if you want your LED to light for 8 hours, that'd be 3.3A*8H=26.4 Ah.

But, that is a minimum.  You will need more because the ratings aren't exact, and because some of the battery's energy will be lost in resistance of the wires and in the battery itself.

---

Current needed in Amperes = (LED power in Watts)/(battery voltage in Volts)

Battery capacity=(current for LED in Amperes)*(desired operation time in hours)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you drive the LED. For example, linear constant current drive, switching mode constant current drive, resistor current limiting, none, etc.

It also depends on the forward voltage drop of the specific LED you intend to drive and how this matches up with the battery voltage.

In general, allow 10 to 20 per cent losses in energy for the drive electronics ( if any ). So that make your battery power around 44 to 48 "watts".

Note that properly speaking, and for my audience of engineering perfectionists, the **watt** is a unit of power dissipation, not power generation or delivery. More correctly speaking your battery is delivering 44 to 48 **volt-amps** of power to an LED which is consuming/dissipating 40 Watts.

Comment: The watt is a unit of power, which is energy per second. Calling it volt-amps, or making distinctions between dissipation, supply, generation, delivery, is not required. I'm not sure where some of the higher rep comments get their ideas from, but they seem to have made you too jumpy. Stand your ground. A battery can supply watts of power, and stores joules of energy, either of which can limit it for an application. Some questioners have trouble with the whole energy per unit time is power thang, which is where the comments usually get directed.

Comment: I agree, no need to worry about where the watt is going to or coming from, it's still a watt.